# Leap AI API возвращает None

Tags: python, api, искусственный-интеллект

Я использую [leap ai api python](https://reference.tryleap.ai/reference/inferencescontroller_generate) и при запросе output возвращает None.

Смотрел документацию, не нашёл.
В браузере запускаю и все работает, получаю ссылку, а через API нет, но токены расходуются.

[image: вот скрин]

Вот код:

```py
from pprint import pprint
from leap_workflows import Leap
leap = Leap( "мой api"
)

response = leap.workflow_runs.workflow(
    workflow_id="wkf_mC8aSaHmOAhFTt",
    input={
        "image_description": "A photo of dog in city, particles, soft-focus, shot on a Sony mirrorless, DSLR, realising lighting and shading, 4k"
    }
)
pprint(response.body['output'])
```